# Why I get different output values with the same declared constants on an event?

Tags: javascript, constants, dom-events, declaration

I have a very weird issue going on. I create two event listeners one for each button and the I just `console.log(e.target.className)`
The button have also inside them an
`<i class='...'/>`. The weird thing is that when I target the elements like this:

```
const btn1 = something1;
const btn2 = something2;
```

It gives me a different result from declaring it like this:

```
const btn1 = something1, btn2 = something2;
```

What is going on with this? Do these two ways of the declaration have to do anything with the scope?
What would be preferable and under what circumstances should I use the one rather than the other?
[Here is a pen for a quick review.](https://codepen.io/evangeloskolimitras/pen/jQyLxJ?editors=1111)

**UPDATE**

I also came across another weird 'issue'.
When I try to make a declaration of the two of the above variables like this

```
const /* hit enter here */
btn1 = something1, btn2 = something2
```

I get as a result the class vale of the button and not the inner `<i class='...'/>`

Comment: In your pen, the second way in the comments looks identical to the first, what am I missing?

Comment: I just updated @Keith..

Comment: Ah, I see what's happening, this is nothing to do with the `const`, it's how events propagate,. A listener will attach to all siblings, `<button><i>`  so it depends on were you click the button, if you hit the `i` tag, or the `button` tag.. Try using `currentTarget` this is the element you attached the event listener onto.

Comment: I see. So how can we get only the add__btn class when hitting that button? Because of I target it right? And @Keith the <i class='...'/> is not an element sibling but an element child.

Comment: If you want the btn, it's just `currentTarget.className`, if you want the `<i>`,  `currentTarget.querySelector("i").className`     yes, should have said child elements,..

Comment: Simple enough! Thanks, @Keith.  My issue was solved!